# Random flip and reverse flip in GAN inside the Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network, data-augmentation

I would like to use tensorflows random flip to train the generator part of a gan network only. For that i would like a way to either flip the image randomly at the begining of the model and the end.
I don't want to augment the dataset because right now it fits my RAM quit nicely.

Comment: Hi! You can just put ImageDataGenerator which includes Data augmentation features like Flipping the image, blurring, rotation etc in the model creation or loading the dataset itself . Ref [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#two_options_to_use_the_keras_preprocessing_layers), [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: Will this work for Imput and Output Image? I only ever see the capability to flip the input image.

Comment: Yes. You can augment in output images too . Just use the augmentation feature from layers instead of imageGenerators(you can use it in input). Thank you!